# Literal structure for time datatype

Tags: time, types, language-design, dsl, literals

I'm working on a DSL that should support a time literal and am interested in two different things:

1. What language(s) or DSL(s) support a time literal?
2. How is the literal structured?

I'm leaning towards using the following regular expression, extracted from the XSD for XML Schema itself, for identifying a time literal:

```
T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d[+\-]\d\d:\d\d
```

But, despite that inclination, I haven't been able to find a common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use formats from ISO 8601 as appropriate:

- [ISO 8601:2004 (PDF)](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~vgent/calendar/downloads/iso_8601_2004.pdf)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

Two non iso-8601 answers:

1. Emacs lisp has pretty sophisticated treatment of time and date;
2. Likewise [Frink](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#DateTimeHandling).